# Swift AVAudioEngine blocks mic and speakers

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I have an **VoIP** app, do calls with twilio, I'm recording some text with iOS Speech framework, but after I recorded the text using

```
private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
```

The mic and speakers are **blocked**, I can't do a second call because the device mic and speaker doesn't work.

I'm trying to dealloc the memory:

```
self.audioEngine.stop()

inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

self.recognitionRequest = nil
self.recognitionTask = nil

recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks!